# Missing module when types defined

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, tsconfig

I'm having an issue which is causing me a bit of hassle - I'm not the best at setting up projects however, this is as far as I've got.

My entry points should only consist of the index.ts files located within /src/server and /src/client which can be seen in the folder structure below. Each index file contains the import statements which grab the correct files lower down within the structure similar to a package-like structure. I've put the tsconfig.json within the root folder defining the baseUrl and type definitions.

Theoretically, this should work and has been compiled this way before however, when using `tsc` I get the following errors

```
Cannot find module 'module' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Even though `module` is located as a type definition within `node_modules/@modules`. Possibly I am trying to compile this application wrong or it is not reading the tsconfig during compilation. Any help would be appreciated.

File structure:

```
├─ tsconfig.json
└─ src/
   ├─ client/
   ├─ shared/
   ├─ server/
   │  ├─ core/
   │     └─ server.ts
   └─ index.ts
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types", "node_modules/@modules" ],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
  },
  "paths": {
    "client/*": ["./client/*"],
    "server/*": ["./server/*"],
    "shared/*": ["./shared/*"]
  },
  "include": [
    ".eslintrc.json",
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./vite.config.ts"
  ]
}
```